# why filter return [object Object]?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var persons = [
    {name : "jak" , age:20},
    {name : "hasan" , age: 15},
    {name : "reza" , age:18}
];

function adult(el,index,arr){
    if (el.age >= 18)
        return el.name;
    }

    document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = persons.filter(adult);
}
```

I expected jak and reza ,
but i see [object object] [object object].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter needs to return true to keep the element or false otherwise.

See below:

```js
var persons = [{
  name: "jak",
  age: 20
}, {
  name: "hasan",
  age: 15
}, {
  name: "reza",
  age: 18
}];

function adult(el, index, arr) {
  if (el.age >= 18)
    return true;
}

document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = persons.filter(adult).map(function(person) {
  return person.name;
});
```

```html
<div id='x'></div>
```

Reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: good point. It was actually his last line that seemed to be causing him trouble, which I've changed to output the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

You're seeing `[object Object], [object Object]` because you're trying to display an array of objects as a string. That's happening because you seem to think that `filter` creates a string based on it's return value. That's not how `filter` works. [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) takes a function which returns `true` or `false` and creates a new array with only the results that returned `true`.

```
var adults = persons.filter(function(person) {
  return person.age >= 18;
});
```

If you want to map certain elements in an array to something else you can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
var adultNames = adults.map(function(person) {
  return person.name;
});
```

Finally, to convert an array into a single string, you can use [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = adultNames.join('and');
```